# How to add new lines to description of OSMbonuspack marker?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, marker, osmdroid

I am using the [OSMbonuspack](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack) to create markers and want to add a description with separate lines. However, a normal new line character (`\n`) does not work. So I am wondering if it is even possible to do this. But it seems to be such a common thing, so I would expect, that there is a possibility to do so. I tried the following code, but the newline character has no effect:

```
Marker playgroundMarker = new Marker(mapView);
playgroundMarker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude));
playgroundMarker.setTitle(title);
playgroundMarker.setSubDescription("first line\nsecond line");
```

This results in the following description: `first line second line` instead of:

```
first line
second line
```

At the moment my only solution is to use separate the description in two. Using the first part as a snippet (`playgroundMarker.setSnippet(...)`) and the second part as a description (`playgroundMarker.setSubDescription(...)`). But there should be a better way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both snippet and subdescription support html tags. 
So this will do the job:

```
playgroundMarker.setSubDescription("first line<br>second line");
```

Comment: How can i display the title and description as a popup or snippet on marker click event?

Comment: Just follow the tutorial.